# Add class to divs which contains an image of a certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi let me start with the codes.

```
<div class="nyhet"> <img src="#" width="785" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet"> <img src="#" width="390" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet"> <img src="#" width="785" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet"> <img src="#" width="390" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet"> <img src="#" width="785" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet"> <img src="#" width="390" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet"> <img src="#" width="785" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet"> <img src="#" width="390" class="attachement-full" /></div>
```

Ok, so basically what I want is that the divs with an image that is 785 should get a class named large added to it, and the divs with an image that is 390 should get a class named small.

So it should look like this.

```
<div class="nyhet large"> <img src="#" width="785" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet small"> <img src="#" width="390" class="attachement-full" /></div>
<div class="nyhet large"> <img src="#" width="785" class="attachement-full" /></div>
```

and so on.
This is what I've tried to so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = $(".nyhet").length;
  for (var i=0; i<x;i++){
    n = $(".attachement-full:eq(i)").attr("width");
    if (n<785) {
      $(".nyhet:eq(i)").addClass("small");
    } else {
      $(".nyhet:eq(i)").addClass("large");
    }
  }
});
```

I chose to use .attr instead of .width because the images probably won't be finished loading  when the script runs.

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code snippet I couldn't tell if you wanted to set images with width `786` as larget so heres a way to do it for ranges:

```
$(".nyhet img").each(function() {
    var $par = $(this).parent(".nyhet");
    if(this.offsetWidth >= 785) {
        $par.addClass("large");
    } else {
        $par.addClass("small");
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm wondering, will this go through all the imgs and change the corresponding div?

And also do I have to use $(window).on('load', function() to make it work considering the images needs time to load?

Yeah, cause it didn't work. :p

Comment: Hmmm, good point, you would have wait for the images to actually load to calculate the `offsetWidth`. You could change that line to `$(this).attr("width");` If you are going to set the width attribute on each image. This will go through each `img` with a parent element with class `.nyhet` but not check images without the parent `.nyhet`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use one selector:

```
$("img[width=785]").parent(".nyhet").addClass("large");
$("img[width=390]").parent(".nyhet").addClass("small");
```

Comment: Add `.parent(".nyhet")`